# Portable wikitext generating a link to a certain page in an uploaded PDF file

Tags: mediawiki

I have a private wiki I sync between several computers.  I have a hyperlink that opens a pdf file at a specific page:

[http://172.16.100.15/mediawiki-1.35.6/images/b/b3/USERS_GUIDE_TO_MODEL.pdf#page=33 Link to page 33 in manual].  This opens the pdf to the specified page.

Since my 3 wiki's have different IP addresses I need to have the ability to replace that 172.16.100.15 with something that automatically gives the ip address of the current machine.

I tried the following but the `#page=33` functionality doesn't work - doesn't open the pdf to the specified page.  This below just opens the pdf to page 1.

[[:File:USERS_GUIDE_TO_MODEL.pdf#page=33 | Test]]

I also tried this below with same result.

[[Media:USERS_GUIDE_TO_MODEL.pdf#page=33]]

This approach below works (I'm using the PdfHandler extension) but not as a clickable link.  It just opens the pdf to that page and shows it.  I want it to be a link that I click which then opens pdf in browser to that page.

[[File:USERS_GUIDE_TO_MODEL.pdf|page=33]]

What can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of these:

- `[{{fullurl:File:USERS_GUIDE_TO_MODEL.pdf|page=33}} Link to page 33 in manual]` — generates absolute URL, which may be protocol-relative, if `$wgServer` is such,
- `[{{canonicalurl:File:USERS_GUIDE_TO_MODEL.pdf|page=33}} Link to page 33 in manual]` — absolute URL with protocol,
- `[{{filepath:USERS_GUIDE_TO_MODEL.pdf}}#page=33 Link to page 33 in manual]` — will open the required page of the PDF in full screen mode.

It is assumed that *[PdfHadler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PdfHandler)* is installed.

Comment: Thank you.  The first 2 work, but they don't open the pdf in full page mode.  Then clicking on the pdf will open the full page mode but to the 1st page.  The 3rd doesn't show up correctly in the wiki - it is just this text: `/mediawiki-1.35.6/index.php?title=File:USERS_GUIDE_TO_MODEL.pdf&page=33 Link to page 33 in manual` and is not clickable.

Comment: And I have PdfHandler installed.

Comment: See the last option in the edited answer.

Comment: I just re-read and caught the word "edited".  Thank you, that 3rd option works perfectly!